# Can I use integers as parameters?

Tags: prolog

How can I know if a person X is descendant of a person Y given the descendancy degree?

I've tried this:

```
descendant(X, Y, 1) :- son(X, Y).
descendant(X, Y, Degree) :- son(X, Z) , descendant(Z, Y, Degree-1).
```

Where `son(X, Y)` returns `yes` if X is son of Y. If `Degree == 1` it returns the correct answer but for `descendant(X, Y, 2)`, for instance, should return `yes` if X is grandson of Y but returns `no`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog is not a functional language. Thus, the `Degree-1` term is not interpreted and evaluated as an expression. For Prolog, `Degree-1` is just a compound term with two arguments. That can be made clear using the standard `write_canonical/1` predicate, which writes a term without using operator notation:

```
?- write_canonical(Degree-1).
-(_,1)
true.
```

Write instead:

```
descendant(X, Y, 1) :-
    son(X, Y).
descendant(X, Y, Degree) :-
    son(X, Z) ,
    descendant(Z, Y, Degree0),
    Degree is Degree0 + 1.
```

The `is/2` standard built-in predicate unifies the left argument with the value of the arithmetic expression in the right argument.

P.S. Note that the alternative `descendant/3` predicate definition I suggest will solve the problem you described but it is not an efficient definition as it is not a *tail-recursive* definition. I.e. the recursive call in the second clause is not the last call in the clause body. This issue can be easily solved, however, by using an *accumulator*.

Comment: Prolog is more.™

Answer (score 5):

**1) Naming:** Does  `son(X,Y)` mean "`X` is the son of `Y`"—or vice-versa? 
`son_of(X,Y)` is better.

**2) Exploit [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics):** We don't need to do general arithmetics here... we only need to count.

---

So let's start [in the **beginning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Beginning)...

```
child_of(abel, adam).           % from source
child_of(abel, eve).
child_of(cain, adam).
child_of(cain, eve).
child_of(enoch, cain).
child_of(irad, enoch).
child_of(mehujael, irad).
child_of(methushael, mehujael).
child_of(lamech, methushael).
child_of(jabal, lamech).
child_of(jabal, adah).
child_of(jubal, lamech).
child_of(jubal, adah).
child_of(tubal_cain, lamech).
child_of(tubal_cain, zillah).
child_of(naamah, lamech).
child_of(naamah, zillah).
child_of(seth, adam).
child_of(seth, eve).
child_of(enos, seth).
child_of(kenan, enos).
child_of(mahalalel, kenan).
child_of(jared, mahalalel).
child_of(enoch, jared).
child_of(methuselah, enoch).
child_of(lamech, methuselah).
child_of(noah, lamech).
child_of(shem, noah).
child_of(ham, noah).
child_of(japheth, noah).
```

Based on `child_of/2` we first define `ancestor_of/2`—this should be nothing new to you!

```
ancestor_of(Y, Z) :-
   child_of(Z, Y).              %   If Z is  a    child of Y ...
                                % then Y is an ancestor of Z.
ancestor_of(X, Z) :-
   child_of(Z, Y),              %   If Z is  a    child of Y ...
   ancestor_of(X, Y).           %  and X is an ancestor of Y ...
                                % then X is an ancestor of Z.
```

Next, we add an additional parameter indicating the distance.

We use `s/1` terms to represent natural numbers and add a new argument to `ancestor_of/2`:

```
ancestor_of_dist(Y, Z, s(0)) :-      
   child_of(Z, Y).              %   If Z is  a    child of Y ... 
                                % then Y is an ancestor of Z with distance = 1."
ancestor_of_dist(X, Z, s(N)) :-      
   child_of(Z, Y),              %   If Z is  a    child of Y ... 
   ancestor_of_dist(X, Y, N).   %  and X is an ancestor of Y with distance N ...
                                % then X is an ancestor of Z with distance N+1.
```

So ... who is grandparent of whom?

```
?- ancestor_of_dist(X, Z, s(s(0))).
   X = adam, Z = enoch
;  X = eve, Z = enoch
;  X = cain, Z = irad
;  X = jared, Z = irad
;  X = enoch, Z = mehujael
;  ... 
;  X = lamech, Z = japheth
;  false.
```